# How can I save wet cookie dough

Tags: cookies

I accidentally added 2/3 cup milk instead of 1/3 to a cookie dough. Now dough is too moist. What can I add to absorb the moisture?

Comment: Doesn't answer the actual question but there is another way to salvage the dough: Depending on what kind of cookies you have you could add more milk (and probably more "wet" ingredients like eggs, sugar; baking powder if needed to) until you get a butter cake batter ...
https://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/2017/05/classic-vanilla-butter-cake-recipe.html
... in case you don't have any flour left for doubling the cookie receipe.

Comment: I haven't actually tried this, hence comment and not answer, but possibly, baking the dough as one big cookie could work. Lower the oven temperature by at least 25 degrees (F) and ignore the timing guidelines: just bake until the middle looks set. You'll get something more cake-like than cookie-like, but it ought to be nice and moist. :)

Answer (score 18):

You could go ahead and add each of the other ingredients (other than the milk) again, doubling the recipe.

If you really want to get fussy, you probably should follow the recipe instructions regarding "creaming butter and sugars"...etc. with that second round of ingredients, but honeslty cookies aren't that particular about technique, so I would just dump them in and mix-em up. Your result should be quite reasonable.

Comment: I would add that skipping the 'creaming...' would depend entirely on what kind of cookies you are making. DON'T skip that step for sugar cookies, snickerdoodles, butter cookies. For peanut butter or chocolate chip your mileage may vary.

Comment: I'm not sure if just doubling the recipe works (it depends on the cookies). In case baking soda is the sole leavening agent: If too much moisture was added at the beginning I'd think this would lead the baking soda act too early and thus resulting flat cookies. If (double-acting) baking powder is used I'd be more confident that the cookies won't be very dense.

Answer (score 3):

You have several options:

- The simplest solution: add flour (and a bit of sugar).
- The true-to-the-recipe solution: double the rest of the ingredients.
- The "I am out of flour and sugar" solution: spread the mix out in the oven (at a low temperature) and dry it, mixing it up regularly to even out the temperature.

Comment: Have you tried the third option and can share your experience? It seems straight forward, but I have a hard time believing it would work (it seems to easy?).

Comment: @Minix not with cookie dough (barely made them) but with other very/too wet doughs such as bread or protein cakes. Flavour was not much impacted, texture might be depending on your recipe.

Comment: I'm skeptical about that third option, too.  It seems like the dough would start to cook at least a little, which I can't help but think would severely impact the texture if not flavor of the finished cookies.  If drying the dough out is the goal, I might refrigerate it uncovered for a while.

Comment: *a bit of sugar* and a pinch of salt,  lest they come out tasting like cardboard.